# AKS cluster network problems

Tags: azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster. I need to connect to the customer's SFTP server from the node AKS. It worked stably but stopped working about a month ago. I started getting a connection error and the connection is timed out. I tried connecting locally and connecting from another AKS cluster. SFTP connection works fine. I created a test SFTP server and was able to connect without problems from the problematic cluster. I am using Calico. Could you tell me where to look to understand where the connection to the customer's SFTP server is blocked? Thanks.

Comment: The default behavior of Calico is to permit all traffic. However, this behavior changes to block all traffic except those that are explicitly allowed by policies when a policy is present.  Please Check network policies once by using this command
kubectl get networkpolicy -A
if any please try to disable and check 
kubectl delete networkpolicy -n yaobank-database default-deny.  Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of Calico is to permit all traffic. However, this behavior changes to block all traffic except those that are explicitly allowed by policies when a policy is present. Please Check network policies. steps below mentioned.

1. Connect to AKS cluster
   [image]
2. verify any network policy exist which conflicts SFTP server.
   **`kubectl get networkpolicy -A`**
3. Disable policy using below command
   **`kubectl delete networkpolicy -n < SFTP Policy Name>`**